# increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected

Tags: r

I want to do a very simple 3D plot with this code:

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(10:1)
z<-cbind(x,y)

persp(x,y,z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in persp.default(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 30,  : 
  increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected
```

what should I do exactly to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
If I change my data. For example for x

```
test<-c(0.4118836, 0.3481329, 0.3582897, 0.3122690, 0.3346040, 0.2409363, 0.2474494, 0.1744042, 0.1589965, 0.2435564)
```

and then

```
x<-test
y<-c(1:10)
z<-matrix(x,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(y))
persp(x,y,z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
```

I am getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message implies, one problem is that in `y<-c(10:1)` the y values do not increase...

Besides, z needs to be an x*y matrix.

So try the following:

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(1:10)
z<-matrix(x,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(y)

persp(x,y,z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for this exmple, this code works fine, but I have test it on another data and get the same error. I have updated my post. could you please take a look on my new data

Comment: Well obviously -- in your vector test, the data is still not in ascending order ! try `x<-sort(test)`instead.

Answer (score 5):

Both `x` and `y` should be increasing, as the Error msg says. Try with `y <- 1:10`.

Moreover, `z` may also be problematic. We read in `?persp`:

> *Notice that persp interprets the z matrix as a table of `f(x[i], y[j])` values, so that the x axis corresponds to row number and the y axis to column number, with column 1 at the bottom, so that with the standard rotation angles, the top left corner of the matrix is displayed at the left hand side, closest to the user.*

An easy way to create `z` is by calling `outer`.

Try e.g.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
z <- outer(x, y, function(xi, yj) xi^2+yj^2)
persp(x, y, z)
```